# How to print (list+i) where i is a variable and (list+i) is a variable name?

Tags: python

```
list1=1
list2=10
list3=100
for i in range (1,4):
  print(listi)
```

For example, I have 3 lists where their names are the same for the list but different from i. How can I print list(i) in a simple way?

Comment: This is usually a bad idea. Create a real  list instead.

Comment: A more direct albeit non Pythonic way is to use the `locals()` dictionary which already contains the variables available in scope. So in your case you need to print `locals()[f'list{i}']` . Same thing can happen for global variables using the built-in `globals()` dictionary